# Cross fading images javascript

Tags: jquery, css

i have one image:

```
 Clown%20Fish
```

onmouseover i have to show another image:

```
 image.jpeg
```

that is over the image:

```
 energy.jpeg
```

(show with webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out property)

i got the first code form here : http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#comments

dose not works...

this is the live demo: http://liveweave.com/6EgbYH

here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>

 #cfnormal {
   position:relative;
   height:281px;
   width:450px;
   margin:0 auto;
 }

 #cf {
   position:relative;
   height:10px;
   width:450px;
   margin:0 auto;
 }


 #cf img {
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   width:450px;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 }


 </style>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>

 <script>
 function change(x)
 {
var element = document.getElementById('imgtop');
element.style.opacity = "0";
 }
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>

 <div id="cf">
   <img id="imgbott" class="bottom" src="./image.jpeg" />
   <img id="imgtop" class="top" src="./energy.jpeg" />
 </div>

 <div id="cfnormal">
   <img onmouseover="change(this)" src="./Clown%20Fish.jpg" />
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit, I am having trouble seeing what the issue you are encountering is? As in, what is happening, and what is supposed to happen or expected to happen, and why you felt it should not be like that.

Comment: Could you possibly show a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can see what's going on, and could you clearly explain the problem?

Comment: So what's the question ?

Comment: dose not works i can't seee the image that is hidden by the one over is show ..

Comment: Made [this short example](http://jsfiddle.net/ENtk7/) to work off.

Comment: http://liveweave.com/6EgbYH

Answer (score 0):

i had to show one image that is over another when a third image fire the event on mouseover

here is the correct code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>

  #cfnormal {
    position:relative;
    height:281px;
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
  }

  #cfnormal img {
    position:relative;
    height:281px;
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
  }

  #cf {
    position:relative;
    height:10px;
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
  }


  #cf img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:450px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  }


  </style>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <script>
  function change(x)
  {
var element = document.getElementById('imgtop');
element.style.opacity = "0";
  }
  function normalImg(x)
  {
var element = document.getElementById('imgtop');
element.style.opacity = "1";
  }
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="cf">
    <img id="imgbott" class="bottom" src="http://youngsskatingcenter.com/nss-            folder/pictures/Many_colors.gif" />
  <img id="imgtop" class="top"       src="http://freepages.genealogy.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~genphotos2/jwline.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div id="cfnormal">
    <img onmouseover="change(this)"  onmouseout="normalImg(this)"       src="http://www.vmapas.com/maps/2748-2/Immagine_Satellitare_Mondo_Occidentale.jpg" />
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: i had to show one image that is over another when a third image fire the event on mouseover ok ?